# ¿Cómo devolver datos de una vista B a una vista A?

Tags: swift2

Mas que un error es saber cómo devolver datos de una vista a otra en Swift es decir tengo vista `A` y vista `B`. Lo normal sería usar `prepareForSegue` y seguir la secuencia pasando datos de la vista `A` a la `B` pero si yo quisiera hacer algo en la vista `B` y regresar algún tipo de respuesta a la vista `A`, ¿cómo se podría hacer?

¿El `prepareForSegue` es bidirecional o solo sigue la sequencia del `Segue` en el `StoryBoard`?

Comment: Utiliza un delegado. Cuando hagas un "dismiss" de la vista, llama al delegado y pasa como parámetros los datos que quieras devolver

Comment: listo @mhergon ya entiendo eso y como hacerlo,  queria saber ¿ Esa es la unica Forma?  osea con el 'prepareForSegue solo puedo mandar datos u objetos en una sola dirección.

Comment: no, no es la única forma. Si tienes una base de datos local como CoreData, también puedes guardar antes de salir y recargar al entrar en la vista A. Otra opción es utilizar NSNotificationCenter y enviar un objeto como parámetro.

Comment: @mhergon perfecto eso queria saber   muchas gracias y con lo del metodo      'prepareForSegue'  solo es para avanzar  no se puede usar nunca para retroceder a una vista anterior

Comment: el problema es usar StoryBoards. Llevo más de 6 años desarrollando para iOS y nada como instanciar controllers a la vieja usanza...

Comment: @mhergon muy agradecido por tus respuestas que solucionan mis dudas muy amable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacer lo que explicas es utilizando el esquema *Delegate*.  Te explico, en el controlador B creas un protocolo que contiene unos métodos.  Uno de estos puede ser `tareaTerminada(datos: String)`.  La forma de implementar esto sería la siguiente:

```
protocol BViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func tareaTerminada(datos: String)
}
```

Puedes utilizar cualquier tipo para los datos, `String, Int, Array, Dictionary...`.  Este código puede ir justo encima de la definición de la clase del controlador, en el mismo fichero.

El siguiente paso es crear una propiedad para el delegado en el controlador B.  Esta propiedad tendrá el tipo del protocolo que acabamos de crear.

```
class BViewController: UIViewcontroller {
    weak var delegate: BViewControllerDelegate?

    // El reto del controlador...
}
```

A continuación vamos a definir el controlador A como el delegado del controlador B y a implementar el método que hemos definido antes en el protocolo, `tareaTerminada(datos: String)`.  El lugar adecuado para hacer esto es en `prepareForSegue` en el controlador A.  En éste método podemos obtener el siguiente controlador (el B) y asignar su delegado. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! BViewController
    // Aquí ponemos a self, es decir el controlador A como delegado de controller, es decir controlador B
    controller.delegate = self 
}
```

Ahora seguimos en el controlador A con la implementación del método del delegado.  Para empezar necesitamos que nuestra clase implemente el protocolo, y después tenemos que implementar el método que hemos definido antes.  Lo puedes hacer así:

```
class AViewController: UIViewController, BViewControllerDelegate {
    // Aquí van todos los otros métodos y propiedades...

    func tareaTerminada(datos: String) {
        print(datos)
        // Aquí ya estas en el controlador A y tienes los datos que querías pasar del controlador B.
        // En éste método puedes hacer lo que quieras con los datos que necesitabas.
    }
}
```

El último paso ya es llamar éste método desde el controlador B para enviar los datos.  Estamos haciendo una tarea en el controlador B, la terminamos y queremos retirar el controlador B para volver a mostrar el A y además pasar los datos a A.  Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
        self.delegate?.tareaTerminada("Los Datos que quieras pasar")
    }
```

De ésta forma retiramos el controlador B y justo cuando termina llamamos al método del delegado, que es A, para darle los datos.

Durante toda la explicación he utilizado *controlador* en vez de *vista*, porqué realmente el que hace las funciones de la app es el controlador.  Espero que te sirva de ayuda, si hay alguna parte de la explicación que no entiendes dímelo.

Comment: Muy Buena Tu respuesta Muy Amable Y Gracias Por el Aporte

Answer (score -1):

Con un `prepareForSegue` puedes establecer atributos del `viewcontroller` al que quieras pasarle tus datos. Si esos datos los vas a usar en muchas vistas lo mejor es que los guardes en un `NSuserdeault` o en `CoreData`.

Comment: Pasar datos entre vistas utilizando persistencia no es para nada correcto. Hay que pasar los datos via atributos únicamente, ya que sino los `viewcontroller` se vuelven dependientes los unos de los otros...